# How to get dynamic columns and map Row Values to Column Header with XSLT 1.0 (second Question)

Tags: xslt-1.0

i got the following XML Data and need to create 2 Tables looking like this with only xsl 1.0

Ribbon Rezept

| Medikament | Dosis | 08:00 | 12:00 | 18:00 | 22:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASPIRIN | 0-0-0-1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Ribbon Medikarte

| Medikament | Dosis | 08:00 | 12:00 | 16:00 | 20:00 | 22:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASPIRIN | 0-0-0-1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| PONSTAN | 1-0-0-1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |

But the result with the below xsl ist not creating the expected tables

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<DATA>

<RIBBON_REZEPT>
<SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO>
  <MRO_INT_REZEPT>
    <MEDIKAMENT_M CR="1">ASPIRIN</MEDIKAMENT_M>
    <DOSIS_M CR="1">0-0-0-1</DOSIS_M>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>08:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>12:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>18:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>1</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>22:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINHEIT_M CR="1">Stk</EINHEIT_M>
  </MRO_INT_REZEPT>
</SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO>
</RIBBON_REZEPT>


<RIBBON_MEDIKARTE>
<SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO>
  <MRO_INT_REZEPT>
    <MEDIKAMENT_M CR="1">ASPIRIN</MEDIKAMENT_M>
    <DOSIS_M CR="1">0-0-0-1</DOSIS_M>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>08:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>12:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>16:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>1</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>20:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINHEIT_M CR="1">Stk</EINHEIT_M>
  </MRO_INT_REZEPT>
  <MRO_INT_REZEPT>
    <MEDIKAMENT_M CR="1">PONSTAN</MEDIKAMENT_M>
    <DOSIS_M CR="1">1-0-0-1</DOSIS_M>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>1</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>08:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>12:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>0</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>16:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINZELDOSIS>
      <DOSIS_N>1</DOSIS_N>
      <ZEIT_T>22:00</ZEIT_T>
    </EINZELDOSIS>
    <EINHEIT_M CR="1">Stk</EINHEIT_M>
  </MRO_INT_REZEPT>
</SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO>
</RIBBON_MEDIKARTE>

</DATA>
```

From [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844134/how-to-get-dynamic-columns-and-map-row-values-to-column-header-with-xslt-1-0) i got a Solution, but as the Times are different within the Sub-Nodes (Ribbon Rezept and Medikarte), it does not work as expected :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" method="html"/>

   <xsl:key match="EINZELDOSIS" name="data-by-time" use="ZEIT_T"/>
   <xsl:key match="EINZELDOSIS" name="data-by-cell" use="concat(ZEIT_T, '|', generate-id(..))"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head charset="ISO-8859-1">
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
          <title>Medilist v2</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Ribbon Rezept</p>
    <xsl:call-template name="RIBBON">
       <xsl:with-param name="medinode" select="/DATA/RIBBON_REZEPT/SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <p>Ribbon Medikarte</p>
    <xsl:call-template name="RIBBON">
       <xsl:with-param name="medinode" select="/DATA/RIBBON_MEDIKARTE/SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RIBBON">
    <xsl:param name="medinode" />

   <xsl:variable name="distinct-times-RTF">
           <xsl:for-each select="$medinode/MRO_INT_REZEPT/EINZELDOSIS[count(. | key('data-by-time', ZEIT_T)[1]) = 1]">
 
           <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="ZEIT_T"/>
               <xsl:copy-of select="ZEIT_T"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>
    
   <xsl:variable name="distinct-times" select="ext:node-set($distinct-times-RTF)/ZEIT_T"/>

   <xsl:variable name="source_document" select="/"/>

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Medi</th>
                <th>Dosis</th>
                <!-- a column header for each distinct time point -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-times">
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="$medinode/MRO_INT_REZEPT">
                <xsl:variable name="row-id" select="generate-id()"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MEDIKAMENT_M"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="DOSIS_M"/>
                    </td>

                    <!-- create a cell for each distinct time point 
-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-times">
                        <xsl:variable name="zeit" select="."/>
                        <td>
                            <!-- get matching data point -->
                            <!-- switch the context back to the source document -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="$source_document">
                                <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-cell', concat($zeit, '|', $row-id))/DOSIS_N"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i've put it as an example here [on fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93YNgXt)

Comment: You need to add the ID or name of the branch ancestor element to the keys. And generate separate lists of distinct times for both.

Comment: i had the Idea to select within the call-template the Nodes releavant for the Table. As the key is document wide defined, it seams to me, that this approach is not working. Is there a way just to use the $medinode ? to get the same result e.g. without the Muenich Key Function.

Comment: A key operates on the entire document - but if you define the key as e.g. `<xsl:key name="data-by-time" match="EINZELDOSIS" use="concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name(../../..))" />` then call it as `key('data-by-time', concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name($branch))` where `$branch` is either `RIBBON_REZEPT` or `RIBBON_MEDIKARTE` then only the descendants of the current branch will be selected.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you, this is working, i've adjusted the fiddle, showing the right result yet. If you post your Comment as the solution, i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has two branches - `RIBBON_REZEPT` and `RIBBON_MEDIKARTE` - with identical structure, apart from the name. In order to limit the first key to the current branch, you need to add the ID or the name of the branch to its value.

Instead of:

```
<xsl:key match="EINZELDOSIS" name="data-by-time" use="ZEIT_T"/>
```

define the key as:

```
<xsl:key match="EINZELDOSIS" name="data-by-time" use="concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name(../../..))" />
```

then call it as:

```
key('data-by-time', concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name($branch))
```

where `$branch` is either `RIBBON_REZEPT` or `RIBBON_MEDIKARTE`.

The other key is already limited to the current `MRO_INT_REZEPT`, so it can stay as it is.

---

With some streamlining, your stylesheet could look like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="data-by-time" match="EINZELDOSIS" use="concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name(../../..))" />
<xsl:key name="data-by-cell" match="EINZELDOSIS" use="concat(ZEIT_T, '|', generate-id(..))" />

<xsl:variable name="source_document" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/DATA">
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Ribbon Rezept</p>
            <xsl:call-template name="create-table">
                <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="RIBBON_REZEPT"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <p>Ribbon Medikarte</p>
            <xsl:call-template name="create-table">
                <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="RIBBON_MEDIKARTE"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-table">
    <xsl:param name="branch"/>
    <xsl:variable name="recepts" select="$branch/SRO_INT_REZEPT_INFO/MRO_INT_REZEPT"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doses" select="$recepts/EINZELDOSIS"/>
    <!-- distinct times -->
    <xsl:variable name="distinct-times-RTF">
        <xsl:for-each select="$doses[count(. | key('data-by-time', concat(ZEIT_T, '|', name($branch)))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="ZEIT_T" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ZEIT_T"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="distinct-times" select="exsl:node-set($distinct-times-RTF)/ZEIT_T" />
    <!-- table -->
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Medikament</th>
                <th>Dosis</th>
                <!-- a column header for each distinct time -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-times">
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="$recepts">
                <xsl:variable name="recept-id" select="generate-id()" />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MEDIKAMENT_M"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="DOSIS_M"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- create a cell for each distinct time -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-times">
                        <xsl:variable name="time" select="." />
                        <td>
                            <!-- switch the context back to the source document -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="$source_document">
                                <!-- get data from the intersection of column (time) and row (recept) -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-cell', concat($time, '|', $recept-id))/DOSIS_N" />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```